# new Int32() usages in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, int

C# compiler allows me to write :

```
int k=new Int32();
```

However , I can't assign any value to it.

2 questions

1) doesnt `new` create a Heap allocation , and if so , what about the stack<->value thing ?

2)I can't do nothing with `int k=new Int32();`. in what scenarios will I use it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All structs (and int/Int32 is a struct) allow new() usage, which just means: initialise the struct to default values, I.e. zero for all fields in the struct. Most structs are immutable - and primitives certainly are. Basically, what you have written is the same as:

```
int k=0;
```

You can do lots of things with that.... But you can't change any properties of zero. Zero is zero is zero.

`new` does not always mean "allocate on the heap".

Comment: +1 and here is a great book on GC, Managed Heap, etc [Jeff Richter's Applied Microsoft .NET Framework Programming](http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Microsoft-Framework-Programming-Pro-Developer/dp/0735614229)

Comment: @JeremyThompson I wonder if its still relevant to today's fw 4.5 ( the book is from 2002)

Comment: @Royi that is a fair observation - and certainly there have been minor changes (there's a new collection mode, and the limits on large objects / arrays have changed). The core might still be useful info, but I don't think it is "necessary reading" for this question:)

Comment: Still it is a great read, the GC enhancements in this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx) focus on .Net 4.5 client/server enhancements, other than that I'm not sure of any major surgery.